# Upgrading from Visual Studios 2012 and TFS 2012 to 2015

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2015, tfs, tfs-2015

While upgrading from visual Studios 2012 and TFS 2012 to 2015 version , What will be the impact on Existing Sharepoint Templates and other stuffs ?

Comment: Your own sharepoint templates? The TFS Sharepoint extensions? Which version of SharePoint?

Comment: I have Sharepoint 2013 foundation server ... will the upgradation from vs and tfs 2012 to 2015 will affect anything on the existing sharepoint 2013 solutions or templates , etc ?

Comment: With the Visual Studio 2015 Office Developer Tools installed, you'll get support for SharePoint 2013. I'm personally not aware of issues. TFS integration works with SP2013, though you'll need to follow the extra install steps to upgrade the SharePoint parts for TFS if you're using them.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is whether upgrading your Visual Studio and TFS version from 2012 to 2015 will affect your existing code (maybe SharePoint site templates, features etc.) - The answer is no, it will not.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will be impact on Existing Sharepoint **Templates** and other **stuffs** if you are in-place upgrade. Just install the Visual Studio 2015 Office Developer Tools for support SharePoint 2013.

Please reference below articles for the upgrade with Shareoint:

- [In-Place upgrade to Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2015 from TFS
  2013](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2015/09/17/in-place-upgrade-to-team-foundation-server-tfs-2015-from-tfs-2013/)
- [Migration Update from Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2013 to TFS 2015
  (With Reporting and SharePoint)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2015/09/30/migration-update-from-team-foundation-server-tfs-2013-to-tfs-2015-with-reporting-and-sharepoint/)